# Wordpress print only category parent and subcategory name of the current post in the theme

Tags: wordpress

Basically Ive already assigned the post inside category and subcategory.

Like this : (I made a post and pointed to these categories)

-> Animal (category)
    -> Mammal (subcategory)

Now in the theme I want to echo names of categories of the post ; "Animal" in heading tag1 and "Mammal" in heading tag2 as a structure.
please help me achieve this.

Comment: you need to print this as "-> Animal (category) -> Mammal (subcategory)" or in a list?

Answer (score 2):

> **Put this code in your post loop get post related category:**

```
<?php
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) );
    if ( $categories_list ):
?>
    <span class="cat-links">
    <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', $categories_list ); ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
 $args=array(
   'orderby' => 'name',
   'order' => 'ASC'
  );
 $categories=get_categories($args);
 foreach($categories as $category) { 
      echo "-> $category->cat_name (category) -> ";
      // loop the sub categories
      $sub_categories=get_categories('child_of='. $categoery->cat_ID);
      foreach($sub_categories as $sub_category) { 
        echo "-> $sub_category->cat_name (category) -> ";

      } // end inner loop

  } // end outer loop

 ?>
```